# CSRF verification failed. Request aborted, Reason for failure is CSRF cookie not set

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I want to realize a login for my site. I basically followed the online tutorial and followed the same exact way. However, I still get an error (CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.), when submitting my registration form. Can somebody tell me what raised this error and how to fix it?

Here is my code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.status import (
    HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
    HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,
    HTTP_200_OK
)
from rest_framework import status,views
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login,logout
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from rest_framework.decorators import permission_classes
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny


@csrf_exempt
@api_view(["POST"])
@permission_classes((AllowAny,))
def login(request):
    username = request.data.get("username")
    password = request.data.get("password")
    if username is None or password is None:
        return Response({'error': 'Please provide both username and 
password'},
                    status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
if not user:
    return Response({'error': 'Invalid Credentials'},
                    status=HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
token, _ = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
return Response({'token': token.key},
                status=HTTP_200_OK)
```

Getting output:

```
Forbidden (403)

CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

You are seeing this message because this site requires a CSRF cookie when submitting forms. This cookie is required for security reasons, to ensure that your browser is not being hijacked by third parties.

 If you have configured your browser to disable cookies, please re-enable them, at least for this site, or for 'same-origin' requests.
```

Answer (score 1):

`@csrf_exempt` tells your view to not look for `csrf_token` although the website requires one. Remove `@csrf_exempt` from your view and pass in your form in your template a `{% csrf_token %}` i.e.

```
<form action='/login' method='POST'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type='text' name='username'/>
    <input type='password' name='password'/>
</form>
```

Comment: this is the answer if we use Django, but here I am using drf(Django rest framework) without having any template. So, in this how can we proceed further?

Comment: @lohithdevapatla well, either way it is not recommended to remove csrf authentication so `@csrf_exempt` is a bad method.

Comment: Even if I removed @csrf_exempt, I am getting the same error what I was getting before. Can you please help me on this?